# Compiling Just .SWFs ( Module .SWFs ) In An AIR Project

Tags: fdt

It would have been cool to be able to also compile SWF files even in AIR mode.

I have SWF modules on an AIR app that i want to load/unload when necessary. Their code is in the same project than the global AIR app.
It seems i have no choice but using ant or creating a new (flash) project to be able to compile those SWF where a chained task of sub tasks would have done the job if i could compile SWF even in AIR mode.

Last option, build an AIR app for each module and only keep the SWF file... not the best.

Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Referenced Project
2. Create a properties profile and launcher that doesn't start the .SWF

### Referenced Project

Creating a Referenced Project and use that as a base to generate modules is the preferred way. Some have just use one referenced project to create modules, some use a unique project for each module. You can then move the .SWF to your base project with an [Ant script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

[image]

### Properties Profile And Don't Launch With ADL

Since the AIR workflow creates a .SWF, just do that and create different profiles and don't launch the generated .SWF with the ADL. To test the .SWF you can just use an [ANT script](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks#fdt.extSWFViewer.startSWF) to test it.

[image]
[image]